# Cover Female lead pull chains around male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's an isekai; the Female Lead (FL)'s hair might be red.

The FL's whole family got killed by followers of a corrupted god to steal divine power from her adopted sister. Her blonde adopted sister is a future saint. Blondie saved the FL and put a fragment of divine power in FL, and pushed back or sealed the bad god's followers.

The story then skips ahead to when the FL is all grown up. The followers unseal themselves and kidnap the FL to steal blondie's divine power from within the FL. She managed to escape by remembering the original story. She was in a cave with a pond. She jumped in to save the Male Lead (ML), who's a temple knight that was sealed in the pond. So the FL unseals him and they managed to escape the bad guys. In the meantime, blondie goes on her journey to save the FL with her guy.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[Rewriting My Tragic Ending](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rewriting-my-tragic-ending)*. It is licensed by [Manta](https://manta.net/en/series/rewriting-my-tragic-ending?seriesId=2073).

> Alicia Melfont vows to restore the former glory of her house **after the Dark God's agent massacres her family. But when a mysterious book reveals that she's only a supporting character** meant to die for the true protagonist of the story, Alicia decides she won't let some silly book determine her fate.

The cover shows the protagonist holding on to chain leashes for two men.

[image: Cover image]

The story is not an isekai and the protagonist's hair is black or dark brown, not read. The other details match very well.

The first chapter includes an introduction for two important characters besides the protagonist; the saintly blonde Ophelia, and Nix, a priest who is in fact a servant of a dark god. He covets Ophelia's divine powers and attacks the protagonist and her family, killing them all. During this time Ophelia embedded divine power in the protagonist, and Nix returns 10 years later to try to recover it. He kidnaps the female lead, and while she's imprisoned, she discovers a book detailing the story.

She then uses the divine power to escape from her prison. She recalls that Ophelia entered a nearby spring and rescued a man - presumably the male lead - and decides to beat Ophelia to it and save him herself.

[image: Paladin imprisoned in spring]